# Need suggestion on how to embed videos with video Playback control in Adobe AIR project

Tags: javascript, html, air

I am working on an Adobe AIR project that requires that i embed videos with Video play back control. I ve tried embedding .swf but it does not com with video play back controls. I will like advice or suggestion on how to go about this.
I ve used the following codes to embed .swf video but it does not come with playback control butons:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="1200" height="600">
    <param name="movie" value="me.swf"></param>
    <param name="wmode" value="opaque"></param>
</object>
```

Comment: Please always include your approach or some code showing what you have tried so far. This makes it easier to help you. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try ANE library FPNativeUI (iOS only) that can display native video player. The demonstration here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G5IdHnms2Dc . Download example here http://flashpress.ru/blog/ane/native-ui/?lang=en .